# Config Routing to functions other than the default ones

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my controller class I implement my interface, the controller class is a subclass of ApiController

I have a method for my API called Read.
I would like the default Get() to call Read().

Without having to do

```
Get()
{
    Read();
}
```

Also I dont want to do /api/{controller}/{action}/{id}

I'd like /api/{controller}/{id} to route to 
the Read() method instead of Get()

The question is:
Lets say I have a Controller thats called Devices. When a GET request to /api/Devices/ heppens I want it to call my specific method rather than the Get() method of the APIController.

Comment: Whats your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ASP.NET Web API Attribute Routing!  (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/MyController/MyAction")]
public string Read() {
   return "You issued a GET request to the Read method";
}
```

You can do whatever you want with the route, just make sure you map the routes in the `WebApiConfig` like this: `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` (see the article for more info on that).

Comment: can they be inherited from the interface?

Comment: If you're saying that your controller extends from ApiController and implements an interface IMyInterface which contains a definition for Read(), then yes.

Comment: I was wondering if the attributes applied to the interface could be applied inherited into the implementing class. But according to Microsoft its not possible. Here's an article http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2011/08/interface-attributes-class-attributes.html

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now.  Yeah, attributes aren't "inherited" like that; they carry semantic meaning within whatever context they are in (so the attributes on your interface mean something in the context of the interface, and the ones in the controller, i.e. `[HttpGet]` mean something there).